# getting second row value from stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net-2010

I have stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as 
begin
select t.TBarcode, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate from Transaction_tbl t where TBarcode=@carid
declare @transid integer=null
select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid
select count(k.transactid) transid from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid
end

while executing stored procedure i am getting out put like this:

Tbarcode   paid status
1111         0    2

Transid
2
```

Return value
     0

How I can fetch Transid value in vb.net?
I Fetchd first row value like this:

```
Dim cmdcarvalidation As New SqlCommand("carcallvalidation", con.connect)
cmdcarvalidation.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdcarvalidation.Parameters.Add("@carid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = txtTicket.Text
dr = cmdcarvalidation.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read

    tbarcode=dr("Tbarcode")
    payd= dr("paid")
   status= dr("status")
 end while
```

while fetching transid value like this am getting error,,,is there any way to fetch second row value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request the value from DataReader:

```
Transid= dr("Transid")
```

Remember to call Dispose() on every IDisposable member instannce like DataReader, Command an DbConnection

Comment: Transid output is getting second row,,,so i am not able to fetch like this

Comment: Ok, I see. You are using multiple result sets. 
In that case, add a line to get next result set firs:
if(id.NextResult())
{
    if(idr.Read())
    {
        Transid= dr("Transid")
    }
}